# How to join two quantum circuits where measurement of one circuit is input to the other, with some classical changes?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit, tensorflow-quantum, quantumgrid

I am working on implementing a substitution table in qiskit, for which i want to use a lookup table approach. I initialize a quantum circuit with my intended state which after certain operations is measured and substituted by lookup table. Now, i initialize another quantum circuit with the output from lookup table.

Now, i want to implement lookup table without measurement. Rather some classical control on the quantum circuit to implement lookup table.

I tried to measure the first circuit, the counts of first circuit is taken as input for the second circuit.  But I want to use any other method, which helps me to solve that without measuring first circuit.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Can you edit this to better make clear what you are specifically asking for in Qiskit.